# Why using hash trees instead using a single hash value?

Tags: hash, hash-tree

If one have files $x_1, x_2, .., x_n$. What are the benefits of using hashing trees $-$ also known as Merkle trees $-$ (for example in git) instead of computing one hash value $h(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Merkle tree is used for effective retrieving or sending data on the network that you can [send](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/241965/86735)/[retrieve](/a/71313/18298) the data on any order and verify the current data with additional $O(\log n)$-data transmit and in $O(\log n)$-time. Actually, only the root hash is stored $O(1)$. While keeping the root hash any data retrieved/send is verified.

\begin{array}{lcr}
 & \text{With Merkle Tree } &  \\ \hline
\text{receiver} & \text{data transmit } & \text{Databank} \\ \hline
\text{keeps the root hash} & & \text{keeps the files}\\ 
O(1)\text{-space} & & \\ 
& \xrightarrow{\text{request the ith file }} & \\
& \xleftarrow{\text{sends ith  file with the }O(\log n) \text{ siblings to the root hash}}\\
\text{Verification in} & & \\
O(\log n)\text{- time} & & 
\end{array}

The above diagram that you are the owner of the data and [outsourced it](/a/71313/18298). If the [client wants to upload the data](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/241965/86735), first they can transmit the root hash digitally signed to the server where the diagram continues.

If you use one hash, then to verify you need to send/receive all of the data and compute the hash all over it $O(n)$-data transmit and in $O(n)$-time. There are also parallel hashing like ParallelHash of the SHA3 or Blake3. This can decrease the hashing time of $h(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$ if you have more than one core/thread. In theory, this is $O(\log n)$, however, in practice, it may not. Still, to verify, one needs to transfer all at once, i.e.  $O(n)$-data transmit.

\begin{array}{lcr}
 & \text{With Single Hash } &  \\ \hline
\text{receiver} & \text{data transmit } & \text{Databank} \\ \hline
\text{keep hash} & & \text{keeps the files}\\ 
O(1)\text{-space} & & \\ 
& \xrightarrow{\text{request the ith file }} & \\
& \xleftarrow{\text{sends all files } O( n) \text{-data transmit}}\\
\text{Verification in} & & \\
O(n)\text{- time} & & 
\end{array}

**Therefore** the benefit is reduced hash time and reduced data transmission.

Comment: Whoever upvotes this answer, please go and read and upvote the Squamish's amazing answer, too. It is linked.

Comment: But this way you're assuming that the tree is binary. What if the tree is not binary?

Comment: @funidentifier There are works in [Academia](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.01994.pdf) about those, Obviously, the depth of the tree is decreased, however, one will need more siblings than the depth. One needs to look at each case. Note that by Definition a [Merkle Tree is Binary Tree](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-48184-2_32.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your  answer. Whether the tree is binary or not, I think  that the point of "efficient verifications" still hold. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, That is the point.